# rubyのクラスメソッドについて

Tags: ruby

Rrubyのクラスについての質問です。以下rubyコードを作成

```
puts '===================================================='
puts '1 クラスの作成、インスタンスメソッド、ゲッター、セッター'
puts '===================================================='

class Warrior

    @@class_hensu

    @class_instance_hensu

    def initialize(name:, hp:, ap:)

　　　　　puts 'phpでいうコンストラクタ'

        @name = name
        @hp = hp
        @ap = ap
        puts "#{@name}:#{@hp}:#{@ap}"
        puts @mirenai
        p @nildesu
        puts 'initialize終了'
    end

    #インスタンスメソッド
    def attack
        a = '攻撃！'
        puts a
        puts "#{@name}は#{@ap}のダメージを与えた"
    end

    # ゲッターメソッド
    def name
        @name
    end

    # セッターメソッド
    def name=(name)
        @name = name
    end

    #attr_accessorでゲッターセッターが自動で作れる
    attr_accessor :hp

    # ゲッター、セッターをそれぞれ省略した形で
    attr_reader :ap
    attr_writer :ap
end

yamada = Warrior.new(name: '山田', hp: 1000, ap: 1000)
yamada.attack
yamada.name = 'さとう'
yamada.attack

puts
puts '============================='
puts '2 クラスの統合'
puts '============================='

class Warrior
    def call
        voice = 'ガンガン行こうぜ!'
        puts voice
    end
end

yamada.call

puts
puts
puts '=========================='
puts '3 クラスメソッド'
puts '=========================='

class Warrior

    def self.run
        puts '大草原へ走り去った'
    end

    class << self
        def create_warriors(warriors)
            warriors.map do |warrior|
                Warrior.new(warrior[:name], warrior[:hp], warrior[:ap])
            end
        end
    end
end

Warrior.run

warriors_info = [
    {name: '山田', hp: 1000, ap: 1000},
    {name: 'さとう', hp:500, ap: 500}
]

warriors = Warrior.create_warriors(warriors_info)
warriors.each do |warrior|
    puts warrior.attack
end
```

上記コードを書き、ターミナルにて以下、

```
====================================================
1 クラスの作成、インスタンスメソッド、ゲッター、セッター
====================================================
phpでいうコンストラクタ
山田:1000:1000

nil
initialize終了
攻撃！
山田は1000のダメージを与えた
攻撃！
さとうは1000のダメージを与えた

=============================
2 クラスの統合
=============================
ガンガン行こうぜ!

==========================
3 クラスメソッド
==========================
大草原へ走り去った
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from sample06.rb:102:in `<main>'
    4: from sample06.rb:88:in `create_warriors'
    3: from sample06.rb:88:in `map'
    2: from sample06.rb:89:in `block in create_warriors'
    1: from sample06.rb:89:in `new'
sample06.rb:14:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0; required keywords: name, hp, ap) (ArgumentError)
```

と表示されました。おそらく

```
class << self
        def create_warriors(warriors)
            warriors.map do |warrior|
                Warrior.new(warrior[:name], warrior[:hp], warrior[:ap])
            end
        end
    end
```

又は

```
warriors_info = [
    {name: '山田', hp: 1000, ap: 1000},
    {name: 'さとう', hp:500, ap: 500}
]
```

の箇所にて引数の渡し方に問題があるのかなとは思い、調べてみたのですが改善策が見つからず、
はまり込んでしまっている状況のため、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

ご推察の通り、newメソッドへの引数の渡し方の問題となります。

```
        warriors.map do |warrior|
            Warrior.new(warrior[:name], warrior[:hp], warrior[:ap])
        end
```

の部分を以下のようにすれば動作するかと思われます。

```
        warriors.map do |warrior|
             Warrior.new(name:warrior[:name], hp:warrior[:hp], ap:warrior[:ap])
        end
```

また、「ハッシュからキーワード引数への自動変換する」というrubyの機能を用いるなら以下のような呼び出しも可能となります。

```
        warriors.map do |warrior|
             Warrior.new(warrior)
        end
```

ただし、この「ハッシュからキーワード引数への自動変換する」という機能は[Ruby 2.7 から非推奨](https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2019_10_31/82588)となるという話です。ご注意ください。